# How to power an LED with a thermocouple

Tags: led, thermocouple

I'm looking for a device that can convert mV to the minimum required to power an LED. I'm thinking of having a thermocouple or thermopile that will be heated by a constant flame.

I've talked with several guys and they all agree in having a booster.

This device needs to be smaller than a golf ball.

Comment: You will need a much higher voltage that what is provided by a single thermocouple. A practical [thermopile](http://www.aqpl43.dsl.pipex.com/MUSEUM/POWER/thermoelectric/thermoelectric.htm) consists of maybe a 100 thermocouples in series.

Comment: Consider a Peltier device - may supply the required voltage directly.

Comment: @pjc50 - A peltier is basically a bunch of thermopiles in series anyways.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of IC products made for this purpose, called "energy harvesting".

For example, Analog has several, [one of which](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3109fb.pdf) is shown below:

[image]

A single type J junction (iron - Constantan) requires a temperature difference of around 500-600°C to get 30mV (typical start-up), that particular chip requires 50mV to be guaranteed start-up.

With 10 type J junctions in series you can guarantee start-up with a temperature difference of only about 100°C  (the more current drawn, the higher temperature difference required depending on the thermocouple resistance). Type K (Chromel-Alumel) is not quite as high output, but it is less prone to corrosion .

To get lower (electrical) resistance requires thicker wires, which means more heat flow between the hot and cold junctions. More junctions (electrically) in series means heat flow is multiplied proportionally since they are thermally in parallel. As always in thermodynamics, there is no free lunch  and you need to keep the "cold" junction actually cold enough relative to the hot junction with a suitable heatsink or maybe even a fan. Overall conversion efficiency will be rather low compared to Carnot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chip for that:
[Linear](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3108) Ultra Low Voltage Step-Up Converter and Power Manager.

Darned if I could not find the SE answer where I first saw the Linear chip. It took Google.

And then, up pops this news article:
[Body-heat powered flashlight](http://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/story/2013/06/27/technology-google-science-fair-finals-ann-makosinski.html) takes teen to Google Science Fair

Looks like you are scooped!

Answer (score 1):

At the DOLLAR STORE, find a solar powered patio light running off of one single NiCd rechargable battery.  It includes a tiny voltage boosting chip that powers the LED.  not sure if the 500 milivolts of a thermopile will be a sufficient voltage to boost, but it will be close.  worth a try. only costs $1.

Comment: It most likely won’t. Your average solar panel has higher voltage that 500 mV.